# No reverse match error but the function exists?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to implement a `renew` function for a key inventory system. But when I render that page, it shows a Reversematcherror even though I mapped the correct URL and used the correct function name.

Here is my template:(The URL tag is on the super long line all the way to the right)

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>All Borrowed Keys</h1>

    {% if keyinstance_list %}
    <ul>

      {% for keyinst in keyinstance_list %} 
      <li class="{% if keyinst.is_overdue %}text-danger{% endif %}">
        <a href="{% url 'roomkey-detail' keyinst.roomkey.pk %}">{{keyinst.roomkey}}</a> 
        ({{ keyinst.due_back }}) 
        {% if user.is_staff %}
           - {{ keyinst.borrower }}
        {% endif %} 
        {% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}
           - <a href="{% url 'renew_key_user' keyinst.id %}">Renew</a>  
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {% else %}
      <p>There are no keys borrowed.</p>
    {% endif %}  

{% endblock %}
```

My urls.py:

```
path('key/<uuid:pk>/renew/', views.renew_key_user, name='renew-key-user'),
path('key/<int:pk>/detail', views.KeyDetailView.as_view(), name='roomkey-detail'),
```

Views.py:

```
@permission_required('catalog.can_mark_returned')
def renew_key_user(request, pk):
    """
    View function for renewing a specific keyInstance by admin
    """
    key_inst=get_object_or_404(KeyInstance, pk = pk)

    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Create a form instance and populate it with data from the request (binding):
        form = RenewKeyForm(request.POST)

        # Check if the form is valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required (here we just write it to the model due_back field)
            key_inst.due_back = form.cleaned_data['renewal_date']
            key_inst.save()

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('all-borrowed-keys') )

    # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.
    else:
        proposed_renewal_date = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=3)
        form = RenewKeyForm(initial={'renewal_date': proposed_renewal_date,})

    return render(request, 'catalog/roomkey_renew_user.html', {'form': form, 'keyinst':key_inst})



class KeyDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = RoomKey
```

The error is saying

> Reverse for 'views.renew_key_user' not found. 'views.renew_key_user'
>   is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL name contains `-` hyphen not `_` underscore

change this `renew_key_user` to `renew-key-user` in your template

```
 <a href="{% url 'renew-key-user' keyinst.id %}">Renew</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that did indeed solve my issue but if you don't mind me asking, my function was defined as `renew_key_user`, why does my url have to be `renew-key-user`? Thanks!

Comment: you can name anything you want, by changing `name` attribute of `path` function in urls.py, read docs for more [naming-url-patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

Answer (score 1):

Update this line in your template.

```
<a href="{% url 'renew-key-user' keyinst.id %}">Renew</a>
```

as name in url is renew-key-user

```
path('key/<uuid:pk>/renew/', views.renew_key_user, name='renew-key-user'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template is asking for `'roomkey-detail'` but the urls snippet you've provided only shows a url named `'renew-key-user'`. Unless there are more url definitions you're not showing us, the code is failing as expected since it can't find a URL with the name you're asking for.

Comment: sorry for the confusion I have updated my post I do indeed have that template and url in my code.